# MongoDB on Golang, get records that are inserted in the last 15 minutes

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to get records that are inserted in the last 15 minutes.

Although it gives me records that are inserted in the last 15 minutes, after 15 minutes passes, it still shows me records that are inserted after 15 minutes. My code:

```
    if len(userIds) > 0 {
        dashboardAggregations = append(dashboardAggregations, bson.M{"$match": bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$in": userIds}}})
    }
    cursor, err = locationCollection.Aggregate(dbContext, dashboardAggregations)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if len(dashboardAggregations) > 3 {
        dashboardAggregations = dashboardAggregations[:len(dashboardAggregations)-1]
    }
```

Following is my aggregation struct:

```
var dashboardAggregations = bson.A{
    bson.M{
        "$match": bson.M{
            "created_at": bson.M{
                "$gte": primitive.NewDateTimeFromTime(time.Now().Add(-15 * time.Minute)),
            },
        },
    },
    bson.M{
        "$sort": bson.M{
            "serial": -1,
        },
    },
    bson.M{
        "$group": bson.M{
            "_id":   "$userId",
            "users": bson.M{"$push": "$$ROOT"},
        },
    },
}
```

I appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: Why did you sort by `serial`?

Comment: @ttrasn Serials are inserted sequentially, so the biggest serial is the latest serial added and I needed to sort serials by the latest ones

Answer (score 1):

create new match aggregation of checking user

```
bson.M{
        "$match": bson.M{
            "created_at": bson.M{
                "$gte": primitive.NewDateTimeFromTime(time.Now().Add(-15 * time.Minute)),
            },
            "user_id": "123123133123",
        },
    },
```

and this aggregation if user parameter don't exist

```
bson.M{
    "$match": bson.M{
        "created_at": bson.M{
            "$gte": primitive.NewDateTimeFromTime(time.Now().Add(-15 * time.Minute)),
        },
    },
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but my problem was that I was receiving data inserted longer than 15 minutes, whereas, I wanted the data inserted in the "last 15 minutes"

Comment: ok , I got it , first you should sort all data with `create_at : -1` then group and push to new field like `dates` , after that use `addFields : {lastDate:{$first:"$dates"}}` and in your match aggregation set date of "lastDate"